# Has chrome 32.0.1700.72m issues with -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1) within <video>?

Tags: css

Before Chrome version 32.0.1700.72m, the following construction used to work fine :

```
<video  id="localvideo" autoplay="autoplay" muted="true" 
  style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);">
</video>
```

In this way I get the camera in the video frame in a flipped presentation.

The `-webkit-transform:scaleX(-1);`  seems to cause an issue in combination with Chrome 32.0.1700.72m since the video / camera is not showed anymore. The video frame remains blank. When I remove this parameter the camera works fine again.

Is this a bug, or has something been changed in the way how to call the `scaleX` method ?

Please advice.

Kind regards,    - Dirk Gooris

Comment: Well for one, this isn't a javascript question. At most it's HTML and CSS.

Comment: @BenM I like to wait for an explanation to make sure.

Comment: I noticed that when I remove the -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1); within the <video>, but control the scaleX with the following javascript call, this problem is there again:
 
   document.getElementById("localvideo").style.webkitTransform='scaleX(-1)';

From that point of view it could be argued that it includes javascript.

Comment: Issue has been solved in Chrome version  33.0.1750.117 m

Kind regards,  Dirk Gooris